# Java multiple program write on same text file

Tags: java

I have two separate programs `NumberWriter.java` writes few numbers to `log.txt` file and `CharWriter.java`  writes few numbers to `log.txt` file. If I run both program simultaneously (run almost same time independently from two different console) then there is no error or exception i.e. both run successfully.Then I was expecting to get file content mixing of numbers and characters at `log.txt` file but getting only either number or character.

I totally failed to find the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

**NumberWriter.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class NumberWriter {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("log.txt");
        for (int i = 01; i < 10; i++)  {
            fw.append(String.valueOf(i) + "\r\n");
            System.out.println("NumberWriter: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        fw.close();
        System.out.println("number write done!");
    }
}
```

**CharWriter.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class CharWriter {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("log.txt");
        String s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        for (int i = 01; i < 10; i++)  {
            fw.append(s.charAt(i) + "\r\n");
            System.out.println("CharWriter: " + s.charAt(i));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        fw.close();
        System.out.println("char write done!");
    }
}
```

**log.txt** file content after running both program simultaneously

either

```
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

or

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**EDIT:** Both program are running without exception and error So I was expecting to get mixture of character and numbers. What is lagging of my understanding.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are any such guarantees for concurrent writes to a file.

Comment: @biziclop both are running without exception at same time. Thats why I was expecting mixture of number and character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bug.

All modern OSes have a file system write lock, so that only one person / program can write to that file at any one time. If you do some investigating, you should find that when you run both simultaneously, one will fail with an IOException

Comment: Your "understanding" is "lagging"? Well now .... you should see a doctor about that ...

Comment: Are probably executing both from within another program on console batch file? If so, you might not be seeing the Exception if you are not reading the processes' out and error streams

Comment: @mmuzahid if you're running from the console, then this is only because the first is already finished executing before the second begins, and then the second overwrites the first. To confirm, add `Thread.sleep(15000);` to the bottom of your main methods

Comment: @ControlAltDel  After following your advice I'm getting both Character and Number. But There are not overlapping just one after another i.e. after all numbers prints all character

Comment: @ControlAltDel UPVOTED your answer but still facing few problem. Thanks

Comment: Okay sorry, my previous advice was to put Thread.sleep at the end of main, which was wrong. Move it above `fw.close` in both methods and tell me what happens

Comment: @ControlAltDel Still ambiguous result. Thanks for your valuable time , I'm planning to try any third party library.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what happens.  Both Java and the OS buffer the output so it is unlikely you would *ever* see interleaved output.  You are writing only 10 bytes, which will be buffered in memory and not actually written until the file is closed.

This is an area where the behavior depends on the interactions of multiple moving parts (your program, the Java I/O system, the OS) and without file locking the behavior is non-deterministic.

I suggest you modify your code as follows:

1. Write 10000 lines in each program instead of 10
2. Add a 10ms delay inside the loop so both programs take 100 seconds to run
3. Flush the output on each iteration

This will cause actual overlap and let you determine what happens.

Comment: It won't cause overlap because the OS won't let you write to the file from two processes at the same time. See my answer

Comment: @JimGarrison Now problem is it OVERWRITE few numbers by character and vice-versa. getting ambiguous output each time I run.

Comment: @mmuzahid This is why you should never attempt to write in the same file from two independent processes.

Answer (score 0):

What might be closer to what you are looking for is to use a server/client system to write to a shared JTextArea, and then write that to a text file

Comment: There is no need to create a JTextArea. The only reason this would help is because all Swing operations are done on a single thread - the UI thread. You can accomplish merging multiple client messages through the proper use of queuing & threading.